80's magic/evil/walkman movie
I watched a bit of a movie when I was a kid in the 80s and I couldn't see more about it. It's a doubt that has followed me for my whole life, so I'm asking you people for help. All I remember is that it was an 80s style movie where a girl is listening music in a walkman (maybe inside a car) and from the rock music (I think the cassette or the music is haunted or something) a tread of pink energy appears and starts surrounding the girl while it (the energy) starts unbuttonning the girls blouse and she starts to arouse.
I'd really like your help in identifying this movie because I saw this bit of the movie when I was like 8 or something and this doubt has haunted me since. Thank you very much for your help.
I remember this film (or at least the trailer, here are some more scenes)
This above scene is in the trailer.  The film is about a demon haunting a teenage boy.
Some more scenes:
The boy smashes his room up to stop the demon.  His mother comes in and comments that he has smashed his stereo, he pauses for a second and replies "I wanted a new one".
He asks the demon about the scene where the girl's blouse was unbuttoned and the demon replies "cheap thrills".

What do you mean by "doubt" following and haunting you? Do you doubt you saw it, or that it's a movie? I don't understand those bits.

Sounds familiar as one of the Elm Street/Freddy Krueger series of movies, but I don't remember which one.

I can remember the trailer.  This scene is in it.  I have added some extra scenes, I cannot quite remember the film though :-(

If it's the same movie I've been searching for, the devil talks to the boy through his Walkman. It ends with the Priest getting the demon out of the boy by inviting the demon into his body, and as soon as it does he jumps out of the window... and kills himself. Great movie, but I can't find the name either. I'm suprised this movie was forgotten by the world. It is not Trick or treat, or Nightmare on Elm Street.

I think I can add to the original post, there was another similar scene that I remember in a 1980s film where a girl was sitting in a car with headphones on at night. The person she was with went inside a house to get something. The girl was unaware of something pulling up along side of the car and emitting a cloud that went into the walkman or headphone that caused her to be aroused. There was also another scene I vaguely remember that involved a home stereo emitting the same cloud. I think the beginning scene involved a biker dressed completely in black, helmet and all, you couldn't see the

I think it was Trick or Treat (1986)?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092112/?ref_=ttqt_qt_tt
It is a horror film about a demonic rock and roll star that can communicate to a kid when he plays his records backwards.  He can move through radio waves and come out of radios, I believe that girl was playing the car radio when he came out of it and seduced her.
Full movie is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33nGwh0ADIA

Trick or Treat IS the movie - The girl (the part I remember) is at 38:32 and here is the corrected link (NSFW):



